# Need a query to insert 'level' into an adjacent list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so

```
ID               Node                  ParentID
1                 A                        0
2                 B                        1
3                 C                        1
4                 D                        2
5                 E                        2
6                 F                        3
7                 G                        3
8                 H                        3 
9                 I                        4
10                J                        4
11                K                        10
12                L                        11
```

I need a query to generate a 'level' field that shows how many levels deep a particular node is. Example below

```
ID               Node                  ParentID                  Level
1                 A                        0                         1
2                 B                        1                         2
3                 C                        1                         2
4                 D                        2                         3
5                 E                        2                         3
6                 F                        3                         4
7                 G                        3                         4
8                 H                        3                         4 
9                 I                        4                         5
10                J                        4                         5
11                K                        10                        6
12                L                        11                        7
```

Comment: Node `F` (ID=6), it's path from root is 1-3-6, hence it's level should be 3, not 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Id,
       Node,
       ParentID,
       Dense_Rank() Over(Order by ParentID) as Level 
       from Table_Name
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88877c/1)

Comment: This way it gives Level=4 for node F (ID=6), where as it's path from root is 1-3-6, hence it's level is 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` function

```
SELECT i.ID, p.Node, i.ParentID
    ,Dense_Rank() Over(Order by ParentID) as Level
FROM TableName AS i;
```

for more detail visit: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/09/sql-server-2005-sample-example-of-ranking-functions-row_number-rank-dense_rank-ntile/

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to do it will be to get the parent level and increment it by 1 when inserting the data since all other ways are expensive performance wise.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question in regards to providing a query. I think this is the soltuion I will end up using

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
;with tree (ID, ParentID, Level)
as (
    select ID, ParentID, 1 from TableName where ParentID = 0
    union all
    select t.ID, t.ParentID, 1 + tree.Level
    from Tree join TableName t on t.ParentID = Tree.ID
)
select ID, Level from Tree
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you need to set level by grouping `ParentID` then join both tables by `ParentID`.

```
WITH CTE (ParentID, Level)
AS (
    SELECT ParentID
         , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ParentID) AS Level
      FROM Table1
     GROUP BY ParentID
)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Node, t1.ParentID, CTE.Level
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN CTE ON t1.ParentID = CTE.ParentID;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac1eb/18)

---

**Update:** (for MySQL - just to help others)

To do the same in MySQL try to get row number like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Node, t1.ParentID, Tbl.Level
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN
(
  SELECT @Level:=@Level+1 AS Level , ParentID 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ParentID FROM Table1) t
, (SELECT @Level:=0) r
 ORDER BY ParentID
) Tbl
 ON t1.ParentID = Tbl.ParentID;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5863/11)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([ID] int, [Node] varchar(1), [ParentID] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([ID], [Node], [ParentID])
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 0),
    (2, 'B', 1),
    (3, 'C', 1),
    (4, 'D', 2),
    (5, 'E', 2),
    (6, 'F', 3),
    (7, 'G', 3),
    (8, 'H', 3),
    (9, 'I', 4),
    (10, 'J', 4),
    (11, 'K', 10),
    (12, 'L', 11)
;

;WITH CTE ([ID], [ParentID], [Node], [Level])
as (
    SELECT [ID], [ParentID], [Node], 1 FROM #Table1 WHERE ParentID = 0
    UNION all
    select t.[ID], t.[ParentID], t.[Node], 1 + c.[Level]
    from CTE c inner join #Table1 t ON t.[ParentID] = c.[ID]
)
select ID, [Node], [ParentID], [Level] from CTE
ORDER BY [Node]


DROP TABLE #Table1
```